# Image is not responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm still having an issue, I'm not an expert in web programming but i need some help, i have tried everything

here is my code

```
<header class='site-header'>
  <a href='#' class='image-wrapper link'>
    <img src='http://ifixed.mx/es/cotiza/LayerMain.png' alt='example image' />
</header>
```

and here is the css

```
figure img {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%; /* just in case? not nessesary */
}

.image-wrapper img {
/* you can use this class on any resposive image parent */
display: block; /* remove white space on bottom */
width: 100%;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%; /* just in case? not nessesary */
}

.site-header .link {
display: block; /* your link needs to be block in this case */
}
```

and here is the link in where im doing the job, but not working in iOS, mac safari, or chrome or any other browser can any one help me?

[Here is Link](http://ifixed.mx/es/cotiza)

Comment: So what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The `.image-wrapper img { ... }` code that you've included in your question would fix the issue, however this code is *not actually present* in the link you've provided.

Comment: works fine https://jsfiddle.net/3wy11pke/

Comment: As a correction to my previous comment, please see my answer... The CSS snippet *is* present, it's just wrapped in a `@media print` tag.

Comment: you should close that anchor

Comment: i have done everything and still not working [link to css](ifixed.mx/es/cotiza/style.css)

Comment: im trying to make the image fit the browser in smartphones, tablets or desktop browser

Comment: I guess you should accept @Santi as accepted anwser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your image a width in percentage. for example. but will advice to use a background image if you want it look look good during screen sizing

```
.site-header .image-wrapper > img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why OP accepted this answer. The CSS is not the problem, it's *where* OP is putting it - this answer does nothing to address the issue.

Comment: Complicated? I solved his issue. If OP replaced his code with yours, *it would not work*. But if you truly think your answer is the solution, then please tell me... why does your code work, but the `.image-wrapper img` code that OP has in his question *does not*? If you're able to give a real answer to that question that proves why OP's code does not work, but yours does, **in a print tag**, then I'll accept that your answer is correct and mine is not.

Comment: @Santi  True tho. I'm gonna delete my answer so he can accept yours. :)

Comment: Well truthfully I give you a ton of respect for that, although at this point it's not a big deal - I've tried to walk OP through his problem multiple times in the comments below, but he's still having some issues in environments that I cannot test/replicate. You can keep the rep, I just question what OP is after at this point.

Answer (score 2):

The code you included here should work:

```
.image-wrapper img {
    /* you can use this class on any resposive image parent */
    display: block; /* remove white space on bottom */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%; /* just in case? not nessesary */
}
```

However, in the [stylesheet attached to your website](http://ifixed.mx/es/cotiza/style.css), **this section of code is wrapped in a `@media print` tag:**

```
@media print {

    /*...*/

    .image-wrapper img {
    /* you can use this class on any resposive image parent */
    display: block; /* remove white space on bottom */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%; /* just in case? not nessesary */
    }

    /*...*/

}


/* The snippet above should be HERE */
```

Styles included in a `@media print` query will only apply *when printing the page*. If you'd like this to apply to your page as normal, you'll want to move it *out* of the `@media print {...}`.

Comment: i have done everything and still not working [link to css](ifixed.mx/es/cotiza/style.css)

Comment: The link in your comment still has your style in a `@media print` tag...

Comment: i have taken out the stiles at the bottom of css

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the issue... Take a look at [your CSS here](https://pastebin.com/BLmNxyUs). Look at `Line 516` - you are opening a `@media print` tag. Now look at line `Line 583` - The responsive CSS is *inside* the print tag. You need to move it outside.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BNVd7Q6i done moved outside, in chrome is doing well, but in safari or iOS dont

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the environment to replicate Safari or iOS, and the link from your original question has not been updated to include your latest CSS, so I cannot help much more than I have. That being said, I believe I have answered the question you asked - the cross-browser issues you're experiencing now are *supplemental questions*, which are frowned upon. If you original issue is solved, you should post any new issues moving forward *as a new question*.